# How to inform future employer about my decision to stay with current employer

Tags: professionalism, ethics, resignation, raise

I had got good salary offer and position from this MNC company from different city than I'm in currently.

However I got Counteroffer + Retention Bonus from my current employer and I have taken the decision to stay here.

Reason of holding back with current employer is because I have lot of job hops in my resume (No of years = No of job hops) also I'm comfortable staying with the current employer.

But I'm confused that how should I approach new employer to inform this decision without burning bridge with this new employer and Should I inform thru email and wait for them to notice OR call the HR inform him and then formally tell the same on email?

Just for information if this matters, we have 2 months of notice period in my region and it's been 20 days since I have accepted the offer.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere new company's offer

Answer (score 0):

> But I'm confused that how should I approach new employer to inform
>   this decision without burning bridge with this new employer and Should
>   I inform thru email and wait for them to notice OR call the HR inform
>   him and then formally tell the same on email?

Always deliver disappointing information in person (or in this case by phone), then follow up with email.

Call HR. A simple "Thank you for the offer, but I've decided to stay at my current company." would suffice. They may ask why, and you can decide if you want to go into details or not. Then follow up with a thank you email.

Since you have already accepted their offer, and are now reneging on your promise to join them, it's unlikely that you can avoid burning bridges here. These things happen, perhaps this employer won't hold this against you. Just respond professionally and promptly and hope for the best.